# Unsupported discriminator type null for query over column mapped to java.lang.Class

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

We are using Hibernate for ORM and trying to map column of type java.lang.Class. Column is mapped correctly but it is not possible to make query using column "type" in where clause.

We have following entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_entities")
public class MyEntity {

    private Class type;

    @Column(name = "type")
    public Class getType() {
        return type;
    }

    // setter

}
```

And method with query

```
public MyEntity get(Class clazz) {
     Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
     Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(MyEntity.class); 

     criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("type", clazz));

     return (MyEntity) criteria.uniqResult();
}
```

The result is this exception

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: Unsupported discriminator type null
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getTypedValue(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:613) ~[CriteriaQueryTranslator.class:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.criterion.SimpleExpression.getTypedValues(SimpleExpression.java:116) ~[SimpleExpression.class:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getQueryParameters(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:346) ~[CriteriaQueryTranslator.class:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:126) ~[CriteriaLoader.class:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1718) ~[SessionImpl.class:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:380) ~[CriteriaImpl.class:4.3.11.Final]
```

Comment: You don't show what clazz contains, is it null by any chance? Please post the complete code for making the query.

Comment: Thank you, I added full method with criteria query.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a issue in [Jira](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2828).

You could circumvent the issue by storing just the class name in the database and convert back-and-forth when creating.

```
@Column(name = "type")
private String type;

public void setType(Class clazz){
    this.type = clazz.getName();
}

public Class getType() {
    return Class.forName(type); //Exception handling omitted
}
```

And in your DAO:

```
public MyEntity get(Class clazz) {
    return getCurrentSession().createCriteria(MyEntity.class)
      .add(Restrictions.eq("type", clazz.getName())).uniqueresult();
```